# How to render more than one object in OpenGL or DirectX 11/12

Tags: opengl, directx11

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ogg4ZfdBqU
I am new to OpenGL, but I have similar objective as you can see in the video. Can we have one shader for all objects? Is there any sample in OpenGL? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please describe with words what you want. We're lazy and don't like to click on links, and if the owner of the video takes it down, the question will make no sense. A video is great for additional information, but not as a single source of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one shader for refractive/reflective objects and one for objects that have different materials (different textures and surface properties) or you can have one big shader (uber-shader) that will determine in runtime (via uniforms) how the object should be rendered.

There is a bunch of tutorials. The best one, in my humble opinion is this one: http://learnopengl.com/.